# Installing Visual Studio 2017 Community getting error when installing microsoft.visualstudio.AspNet45.features

Tags: windows, visual-studio, windows-10, visual-studio-2017, dism

The error is being caused by Visual Studio Installer 2017 trying to execute the command `C:\WINDOWS\system32\dism.exe" /online /quiet /norestart /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:"netfx4extended-aspnet45" /All /logPath:"C:\Users\lgray\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_setup_20170828185051_001_Microsoft.VisualStudio.AspNet45.Feature.log"`. When I try to execute the same command using the command line tool as administrator I get an error:1206. All attempts made to fix the problem failed. The command cannot work without /ScratchDir set.

Is there a way to set /ScratchDir globally so that all command that ran uses the default or is the a way to append to the command being executed by Visual Studio Installer?

Is there a way to skip the executing of the command?

Anything solution is welcome.

Comment: It *shouldn't* be necessary to specify a scratch directory; is your C drive critically short of disk space?  Is the `TEMP` environment variable set correctly?  Does `C:\Windows\Temp` exist and have the correct permissions?  (Process Monitor might be useful in diagnosing the problem.)

Comment: Thank you for the help. The drive has 121 GB of free space. The user `TEMP` variable is set to `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp` and the System `TEMP` variable is set to `C:\Windows\Temp`. The permission of `C:\Windows\Temp` is set to System with full control. The permission of `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp` is set to `my_username` with full control.

Comment: Does it work if you specify the `/ScratchDir` option but point it at the same folder it would be using anyway?  (You can probably determine which folder it is using by looking at the log file.)  Also, have you tried emptying out the temp folder first?  Theoretically, existing content shouldn't matter, but there may be edge cases.